# How can I refresh a Hive/Impala table from Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, impala, spark-structured-streaming

currently my Spark Structured Streaming goes like this (Sink part displayed only):

```scala
    //Output aggregation query to Parquet in append mode
    aggregationQuery.writeStream
      .format("parquet")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("15 seconds"))
      .partitionBy("date", "hour")
      .option("path", "hdfs://<myip>:8020/user/myuser/spark/proyecto3")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://<myip>:8020/user/myuser/spark/checkpointfolder3")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
```

The above code generates `.parquet` files in the directory defined by **path**.

I have externally defined a **Impala** table that reads from that path, but I need the table to be updated or refreshed after every append of `parquet` files.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `spark.sql("REFRESH TABLE some_name")`

Comment: Where should I try that line of code? Will it work after each new parquet file is generated?

Comment: @messenjah00, did you manage to make this work? Care to share?

Comment: sorry, I couldn't make it work

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the partitions of your table after file sink.

```scala
    import spark.sql
    val query1 = "ALTER TABLE proyecto3 ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (date='20200803') LOCATION '/your/location/proyecto3/date=20200803'"
    sql(s"$query1")

    import spark.sql
    val query2 = "ALTER TABLE proyecto3 ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (hour='104700') LOCATION '/your/location/proyecto3/date=20200803/hour=104700'"
    sql(s"$query2")
```